# USVN is not working

Tags: linux, svn, zend-framework

Today I tried to my USVN on http://192.168.1.2/usvn/ but unfotunately I get this shocking message !!!

> Zend_Session::start() - /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:438): Error #2 session_start(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_o58dtec91alc8r5q8821to20h0, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:442): Error #2 session_write_close(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_o58dtec91alc8r5q8821to20h0, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) Array /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:442): Error #2 session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php5) Array
>
> Trace:
>
> /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.php:124  Zend_Session::start 
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Auth/Storage/Session.php:87  Zend_Session_Namespace::__construct 
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Auth.php:91  Zend_Auth_Storage_Session::__construct
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Auth.php:143 Zend_Auth::getStorage
>   /var/www/usvn/library/USVN/Controller.php:83    Zend_Auth::getIdentity
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php:492    USVN_Controller::preDispatch
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php:285   Zend_Controller_Action::dispatch
>   /var/www/usvn/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php:934 Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard::dispatch
>   /var/www/usvn/public/index.php:5    Zend_Controller_Front::dispatch

So Can you please help!

Answer (score 0):

Your apache/php installation is not able to write files in the `session.save_path`.

Make sure that the user under which apache runs has permissions to read and write in `/var/lib/php5/`.

Normally in every apache installation this should be true by default unless you messed up something with permissions.

After fixing that you're likely to encounter the same issue for usvn repository path. So keep that in mind. The php/apache user is NOT your shell user, so you should check for that user permissions, usually it's `www-data` or `apache`.